# AngularJS bs-typeahead async input - dynamic data

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, typeahead, angular-strap

Please excuse my bad English

I have some difficulties with angular-strap **bs-typeahead async input** (live demo, on site this input is called -> Address async via maps.googleapis.com). 
I notice something on their site http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/ .

I explain this with an example : try to put some letters to "input" and select row from list. Now **$scope.selectedAddress** (live demo) contains selected object. Then click somewhere else to lose focus. As you can see the variable
**$scope.selectedAddress** has changed, it's contains string which override object. Now i have to click on input and select  the same row again, now it contains object permanently. 
This effect is unwanted. How to fix this strange behaviour or maybe this is a bug ? I also notice that this happen when we put object to the ng-model.

Maybe someone from angular community know how to deal with this issue.

My input looks almost the same:

```
<input  ng-model="selectedStop" ng-options="stop.label for stop in busStops"  bs-typeahead> 
busStops = {id: 12, label : "New York"}
```

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this? I am seeing this same behavior on firefox now too?